# Load dojo from local and ESRI packages separately

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

Is there by any chance a way to load dojo packages from my local and then load ESRI javascript api packages which i need?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to load the complete API from your local webserver? Or do you want to load just DOJO from your local, and the mapping components from the CDN online?

Answer (score 1):

although it is certainly possible to reference local Dojo modules in your own application, there is currently no way to make a CDN request for the Esri JS API w/o Dojo.